# Dumping a text file using onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function

Sorry if this has been asked a million times, but I am wondering if there would be much pain in getting my page to work as designed. Currently, I have a large button that users will click. I want to call a function when this button is clicked to create a .txt file (locally for now, server side later) with the date and time stamped in the file, possibly named the same as well.

I have a function displaying date and time at the top of the page, as well as I was able to make the button download a blank text file, but I would like to be able to point this somewhere as well as affect the name and contents.

Here is some of my code:
Button calling a function:

```
 <a href="page2.html"><button onclick="WriteToFile()">Touch to sign in. Date and time are recorded upon touch.</button></a>
```

Displaying the date:

```
  var span = document.getElementById('date');
  function time() {
    var d = new Date();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var w = d.toDateString();
  span.textContent = w + "   " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}
setInterval(time, 1000);
```

Empty file creation (when the button link is pointed to this function, it works):

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
```

Even if I could make the download function pull in and write from the date function, that would be nice. Also not sure where to specify output settings on my .txt file.

This doesn't work at all, might be a reason for that I am not seeing:

```
function WriteToFile(passForm) {

    var fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
    var s = fso.CreateTextFile("/Users/***/Desktop", True);
    s.writeline(document.passForm.input1.value);
    s.writeline(document.passForm.input2.value);
    s.writeline(document.passForm.input3.value);
    s.Close();
 }
```

Any help would be awesome, cheers!

Comment: The [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is a Microsoft only component. It won't work outside of IE. You are not going to be able to save to the local file system for security reasons and that's a very good thing. You could save the data in [`localStorage`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: A file absolutely can be saved locally. It happens exactly as demonstrated above with the "empty" text file. Why that is not saving the _text_ into the file is the question.

Comment: @rberlando - So you pass in text to your `download()` function, along with a file name, and no text is written to the file? And, it is just plain text, why are you encoding the text?

Comment: Nevermind - you clearly are a MS dev (judging from the ASP reference), so you need to know that the download attribute is not supported by IE. https://caniuse.com/#search=download